# Good Programming Practices for Macro Definitions (#define) in C

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

For example, never define a macro like this:

```
#define DANGER 60 + 2
```

This can potentially be dangerous when we do an operation like this:

```
int wrong_value = DANGER * 2; // Expecting 124
```

Instead, define like this because you don't know how the user of the macro may use it:

```
#define HARMLESS (60 + 2)
```

The example is trivial, but that pretty much explains my question. Are there any set of guidelines or best practices that you would recommend when writing a macro?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: That's not a question. It's a statement.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Not only should you put parens around the arguments, you should put parens around the expression returned.

```
#define MIN(a,b)  a < b ? a : b     // WRONG  

int i = MIN(1,2); // works
int i = MIN(1,1+1); // breaks

#define MIN(a,b)  (a) < (b) ? (a) : (b)   // STILL WRONG

int i = MIN(1,2); // works
int i = MIN(1,1+1); // now works
int i = MIN(1,2) + 1; // breaks

#define MIN(a,b)  ((a) < (b) ? (a) : (b))   // GOOD

int i = MIN(1,2); // works
int i = MIN(1,1+1); // now works
int i = MIN(1,2) + 1; // works
```

However, `MIN(3,i++)` is still broken...

The best rule is **only to use #defines only when NO OTHER APPROACH WILL WORK!**  I know you're asking about C instead of C++, but still bear his in mind.

Comment: Maybe you should add a note about using enum instead of defining numeric constants with #define.

Comment: Ack!  MIN(3, i++)!  I never considered that case...  That's gotta suck to debug that!

Comment: Of course, the fix is trivial - make it a function, or take the increment out of that line of code.  I don't agree that macros shouldn't be used except when no other approach will work -  Like any other tool macros can be dangerous if improperly used, but done well they can decrease development time

Answer (score 31):

When doing a macro that is to run its argument and behave like an expression, this is idiomatic:

```
 #define DOIT(x) do { x } while(0)
```

This form has the following advantages:

1. It needs a terminating semicolon
2. It works with nesting and braces, e.g. with if/else

Comment: And what if `x` is only a single statement? For instance `foobar = 42`, do we still need to enclose it into `do{}while(0)`, or just putting it inside parentheses is enough?

Comment: You would still need it if you want 1) the macro to **demand** a terminating semicolon, and 2) to use it as a stand-alone instruction in a one-line if-statement.

Comment: Check this link. It explains it very well : http://kernelnewbies.org/FAQ/DoWhile0

Answer (score 10):

Use parenthesis around the entire macro **and** around each argument referred to in the expansion list:

```
#define MAX(x, y) ((x) > (y) ? (x) : (y))
```

---

Avoid writing macros that evaluate their arguments multiple times.  Such macros will not behave as expected when arguments have side effects:

```
MAX(a++, b);
```

Will evaluate `a++` twice if `a` is greater than `b`.

---

Use UPPERCASE names for macros to make it clear it is a macro and not a function so that the differences can be considered accordingly (another general good practice is not passing arguments that have side effects to functions either).

---

Don't use macros to rename types like this:

```
#define pint int *
```

because it won't behave as expected when someone types

```
pint a, b;
```

Use typedefs instead.

Answer (score 7):

use static const values instead of macros for constant values, integral or other.  The compiler can often optimize them away, and they remain a 1-st class citizen in the language's type system.

```
static const int DANGER = 60 + 2;
```

Comment: Will that really work in standard C? In a header file?

Comment: @Roddy: no, it won't work in C in a header - use an enum instead.

Comment: @John: it depends on the context as to whether this is appropriate.

Answer (score 5):

In the expansion, put parenthesis around the arguments, so that if they pass in a expression you will get the intended behavior.

```
#define LESS_THAN(X,Y) (((X) < (Y) ? (X) : (Y))
```

Comment: Ironically, this is a bad macro because it evaluates its arguments twice.

Answer (score 5):

Response to the MAX/MIN macros, taken from [GCC hacks in the Linux kernel](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-gcc-hacks/index.html):

```
#define min(x, y) ({                       \
        typeof(x) _min1 = (x);             \
        typeof(y) _min2 = (y);             \
        (void) (&_min1 == &_min2);         \
        _min1 < _min2 ? _min1 : _min2; })
```

Comment: typeof is a gcc extension and should not be used in portable code.

Comment: Agreed with Robert.  Does anyone want to explain what the void cast and expression is there for?

Comment: Also, the use of ({ ...; foo;}) as evaluating to foo. That's a new one on me.

Comment: I wonder if the void cast and expression is trying to tell the compiler that _min1 and _min2 have to be compatible scalars and not be in registers?

Comment: "the use of ({ ...; foo;})" is another GCC extension. That's why it's a GCC hack, not a C hack. Not sure what else, but the void thing stops you using one signed and one unsigned argument. The types of x and y would be compatible, but their pointer types aren't.

Comment: @onebyone: thank you for the explanation of the void cast.

Answer (score 2):

Use fairly unique names for your macros, since they have global scope and can clash with anything, so:

```
#define MAX 10
```

could easily clash with other code, so:

```
#define MYPROJECT_MAX 10
```

or something even more unique, would be better.

I've seen cases where a clash of this kind didn't produce a compile error, but generated slightly wrong code, so it can be quite insidious.

Answer (score 2):

Undefine your macros.

Your `#defines` should matched with an `#undef`.  This prevents the preprocessor from getting clogged up and affecting unintended pieces of code.

Answer (score 2):

For multiple line macros, use a `do { } while (0)`:

```
#define foo(x) do {  \
    (x)++;           \
    printf("%d", x); \
} while(0)
```

Had you done

```
#define foo(x) {     \
    (x)++;           \
    printf("%d", x); \
}
```

instead,

```
if (xyz)
    foo(y);
else
    foo(z);
```

would've failed.

Also, be careful when introducing temporary variables in macros:

```
#define foo(t) do {    \
    int x = (t);       \
    printf("%d\n", x); \
} while(0)

int x = 42;
foo(x);
```

will print `0` and not `42`.

If you have a complicated expression which needs to return a value, you can use the comma operator:

```
#define allocate(foo, len) (foo->tmp = foo->head, foo->head += len, foo->tmp)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're careful and expert, you may be able to accomplish DRY (Don't-Repeat-Yourself) code, by using macros as simple code generators. You do have to explain to other programmers what you're doing, but it can save a lot of code. For example, the list-macro technique:

```
// define a list of variables, error messages, opcodes
// or anything that you have to write multiple things about
#define VARLIST \
    DEFVAR(int, A, 1) \
    DEFVAR(double, B, 2) \
    DEFVAR(int, C, 3) \

// declare the variables
#define DEFVAR(typ, name, val) typ name = (val);
    VARLIST
#undef  DEFVAR

// write a routine to set a variable by name
void SetVar(string varname, double value){
    if (0);
    #define DEFVAR(typ, name, val) else if (varname == #name) name = value;
        VARLIST
    #undef  DEFVAR
    else printf("unrecognized variable %s\n", varname);
}

// write a routine to get a variable's value, given its name
// .. you do it ..
```

Now, if you want to add a new variable, delete one, or rename one, it's a 1-line edit.

Comment: I hope I never have to maintain any code that you write using this idiom.

Comment: Like I said, it takes explanation, which is true of anything but lowest-common-denominator code. If you want to do code generation, it is a way.

Comment: there is a places where it's acceptable. But one should be very careful using this technique.

Comment: Right. Not every useful idea is popular or well-known.

Answer (score 0):

See how I hate this:

```
void bar(void) {
    if(some_cond) {
        #define BAZ ...
        /* some code */
        #undef BAZ
    }
}
```

Always put them like this:

```
void bar(void) {
    if(some_cond) {
#define BAZ ...
        /* some code */
#undef BAZ
    }
}
```

Comment: While I agree with you, this has nothing to do with macros definitions.

Comment: I wish my gripes were as big as that :-)

Comment: well i don't like it :) same with goto labels