# Animation of NSImageView not staying in place while changing frame size

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm using the following code to scale an image slightly larger and then back to its original size:

```
float width = image.image.size.width;
float newWidth = width * 1.05;
float height = image.image.size.height;
float newHeight = height * 1.05;

[NSAnimationContext beginGrouping];
[[NSAnimationContext currentContext] setDuration:.7f];
NSAnimationContext.currentContext.completionHandler = ^{
   [NSAnimationContext beginGrouping];
   [[NSAnimationContext currentContext] setDuration:.7f];
   [[image animator] setFrameSize:NSMakeSize(width, height)];
   [NSAnimationContext endGrouping];
};

[[image animator] setFrameSize:NSMakeSize(newWidth, newHeight)];
[NSAnimationContext endGrouping];
```

The problem is that the image moves slightly up and to the right during the animation instead of staying in place.

How can I keep the image in place during the animation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the method you're using, `-setFrameSize:`, does not alter the view's origin, (which is the lower left hand corner on a Mac), so the view literally grows up and to the right.  Use `-setFrame:` with the animator proxy, or use a transform on the view's layer in conjunction with a [CABasicAnimation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CABasicAnimation_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) to apply the animation to the view's coordinates linearly.

Comment: Can you show me an example of setFrame with the animator proxy?

Comment: It's just a bit of [math](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879643/calculating-new-origin-of-insetted-cgrect-after-its-size-changes).  What about is is confusing?

Comment: Tried this: [image animator] setFrame:NSMakeRect(image.frame.origin.x, image.frame.origin.y, newWidth, newHeight)]; But has the same effect.

Comment: Exactly, because you still aren't transforming the origin coordinates.  Multiply them by 1.05 as well.

Comment: Wow, I'm tired. Sorry about that. Thanks for the help.