# What does the compiler understand in number+Macro in C

Tags: c, macros

following code is given:

```
#define CELSIUS *10

void main()
{
    int testVar=0;

    if(!testVar) testVar = 10CELSIUS;
}
```

My IDE gives me following message: Constant "CELSIUS" has an invalid suffix. But it seems so that the program compiles. Do I have to care about this message?

Comment: You define `CELSIUM` and use `CELSIUS`, is that a typo?

Comment: "But it seems so that the program compiles." [It's only an illusion; it does not compile](http://ideone.com/IlncHy).

Comment: CELSIUM was jsut a mistake. I edited it.

Comment: @xy36 It does not compile either way.

Comment: Well, my IDE says "Build successfull", but it does not create the hexfile...

Comment: @xy36 Well, if there is no hex file, it's hardly a successful build, right?

Answer (score 2):

A suffix is something "added at the end". So when the compiler complains about an invalid suffix at the end of the integer constant, it's upset by the *single* token

```
10CELSIUS
```

as it recognises the `CELSIUS` within as integer suffix. Allowed suffixes are (N1570 § 6.4.4.1/1):

```
u
ul
ull
l
lu
ll
llu
```

*These are small L letters, the up case version of each letter is allowed, too (though not `lL` or `Ll` in any combination)*

They mean **u**nsigned, **l**ong and **l**ong **l**ong and affect the type of the preceding integer constant.

Thus, to achieve macro substitution you need to [separate the integer constant with a space](http://ideone.com/FMNnUl), thus producing the token `CELSIUS` which can then be replaced with `*10` by the preprocessor:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define CELSIUS *10

int main()
{
    int testVar=0;

    if(!testVar) testVar = 10 CELSIUS;
    printf("%d\n", testVar);

    return 0;
}
```

*Note: This is a more modern signature for the main function. Even better (IMO) would be `int main(int argc, char **argv);`*

Comment: `int main()` is not merely "more modern" -- `void main()` has always been wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Becareful. If you use macros like that, you will have a lot of problems in the future. Better use:

```
/*....*/

#define CELSIUS(x)    ((x)*10)

/*....*/

if(!testVar) testVar = CELSIUS(10);
    printf("%d\n", testVar);

/*....*/
```

If you don't do it, you will have a lot of undesiderable behaviours in your code, like

[Good Programming Practices for Macro Definitions (#define) in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321143/good-programming-practices-for-macro-definitions-define-in-c)