# Make 1D array addressable with row and column

Tags: c, chess

I am writing a chess engine using an array (single dimension) in **C**?

```
#define ROW(sq)         (sq >> 3)
#define COL(sq)         (sq & 7)

int board[64] = {
   0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,
   8,9,10,11,12,13,,14,15,
   .......................
   .......................
   56,57,48,59,60,61,62,63
}
```

Now:
To get the row and col of number 11 I use this:

```
int r = ROW(11);
int c = COL(11);
```

It gives:

```
r = 1
c = 3
```

Please help me to write a function so that it takes the parameter as `r` and `c` and gives the correct square like:

```
sq = fnc(r,c);
sq = fnc(1,3);
sq = 11;
```

Comment: have you considered `int board[8][8]`?,, or is single dimension a requirement?

Comment: @GAURANGVYAS: A 2D array is not the same as a 1D array. Even for a variable sized array, it makes no sense not to use a 2D array.

Comment: @Olaf My fault. Commented without properly seeing the question.

Comment: I know this is super old but I disagree with "there is no reason not to use a 2D array". A 2D array is laid out in memory exactly the same as a 1D array. Its literally an array of arrays. There's nothing wrong with using a 1D array as your data and choosing to draw it as a 2D visual grid. Its perfectly fine to split the data configuration from its visual representation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to calculate `row * MAX_COL + col` where `MAX_COL = 8`. With `row * MAX_COL` you will go into the next row, like the following figure shows:

```
                   1 * 8 ---                 2 * 8 ---
                           |                         |
|         row = 0        | v       row = 1         | v       row = 2
| 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7 | 8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15 | 16 ...
```

If you want a macro which uses the global variable `board`:

```
#define FIELD(row,col) board[(row) * 8 + (col)]
```

or as function which also uses the global defined `board` variable:

```
inline int FIELD (int row, int col)
{
   return board[row * 8 + col]
}
```

if you want to pass the board as array to the function you can do the following, where `int boardArr[]` [decays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1461449/8051589) to a pointer:

```
inline int FIELD (int boardArr[], int row, int col)
{
   return boardArr[row * 8 + col]
}
```

---

Also you should change your macro definitions, because they are unsafe if the parameter that is passed is a value that is used in a calculation. You can read it [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/321173/8051589). So you should use braces around the parameters `sq`:

```
#define ROW(sq)   ((sq) >> 3)
#define COL(sq)   ((sq) & 7)
```

It would be even better to use inline functions as it is also said in the SO answer.

Answer (score 1):

If your board is always 8x8, you can see that each `r` starts at 0, 8, 16... and each `c` is just the offset from those initial points, so given an `r` and `c`, you can calculate the array index by `board[(r * 8) + c]` to get the corresponding piece.

Answer (score 1):

This is best approached using a two-dimensional array because that way you can simply access `board[r][c]`.

If you (or your professor) insist on a one-dimensional array, this macro will do what you want:

```
#define GET_PIECE(r, c) (board[((c) + (8) * (r))])
```

Notice how everything is wrapped in parentheses. [This is very important with macros!](http://scienceblogs.com/goodmath/2007/12/17/macros-why-theyre-evil/)

A better solution would be to use an [inline function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_function).