# Creating environment for closure in a macro in Rust

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I'm trying to achieve something like this (simplified):

```
macro_rules! atest {
    ($closure:tt) => {
        let x = 5;
        println!("Result is {}", $closure())
    };
}

fn main() {
    //let x = 50;
    atest!((|| 5 + x));
}
```

It does not work because the argument to the `atest` macro is considered by the compiler before macro evaluation:

```
error[E0425]: cannot find value `x` in this scope
  --> src/main.rs:10:20
   |
10 |     atest!((|| 5 + x));
   |                    ^ not found in this scope
```

Is it possible to make this work? My understanding was that macros are expanded before compilation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Peter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50319024/3650362) explains why what you're doing won't work. This is part of what's referred to as "macro hygiene": things declared inside macros can't "leak" into the surrounding scope.

A common workaround for the problem you're facing is to pass the name of the identifier into the macro as another argument:

```
macro_rules! atest {
    ($x:ident, $closure:tt) => {
        let $x = 5;
        println!("Result is {}", $closure())
    };
}

fn main() {
    atest!(x, (|| 5 + x));
}
```

This will work because naming `x` puts it in the caller's scope, even though the declaration is inside the macro.

You might notice that the closure is kind of unnecessary, at least in this example -- you could just pass `5 + x` as an expression to the macro and have it expanded inline.

```
macro_rules! atest {
    ($x:ident, $value:expr) => {
        let $x = 5;
        println!("Result is {}", $value)
    };
}
```

You call this macro like `atest!(x, 5 + x)`, which looks a little bit like a closure of its own. That might give you the idea of writing `atest!(|x| 5 + x)` instead. And that will also work, with a variable scoped to the closure:

```
macro_rules! atest {
    ($closure:expr) => {
        let x = 5;
        println!("Result is {}", $closure(x))
    };
}
```

### References

- [Macros in Rust pt1](https://www.ncameron.org/blog/macros-in-rust-pt1/)

Answer (score 5):

> Is it possible to make this work? My understanding was that macros are expanded before compilation?

Macros are expanded before compilation, but not before *parsing*. The raw input code has already been parsed and macros operate on an abstract syntax tree, not on text. For example, the closure is already understood to be a closure, and its free variables are already bound to variables in its lexical scope.

This is different to some other languages macros, for example [C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321143/good-programming-practices-for-macro-definitions-define-in-c#321156), which operate on raw text, and let you screw things up pretty badly if you're not careful.

Comment: thanks, I know that macros are working on AST, but did not realized how free variable references are handled. I thought that macro pieces are fit in the right places in AST before binding variables.  But solution from trentcl worked great -  having added :ident params to macro introduced variables at right place.