# How to match a closure with argument in a Rust macro

Tags: rust, macros

I'm wondering, how to match by a macro? Something like this:

```
macro_rules! call_this_closure {
    ($closure:???) => {
        let x = 0;
        $closure(x);
    };
}

fn main() {

    call_this_closure!(|x|println!("{}", x));
}
```

I found [Creating environment for closure in a macro in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50318744/creating-environment-for-closure-in-a-macro-in-rust) but it uses the trick to transform the macro in a `tt` so it cannot have arguments: `(|| 5 + x)`. In my case, I want the macro to have arguments.

I know it can be solved with a generic function like this:

```
pub fn call_this_closure<F, A, R>(&mut self, f: F) -> R
    where F: Fn(&mut A) -> R {
    //...
}
```

but I actually need a closure in my problem.

Comment: See the last solution in the answer you linked.

Comment: [The duplicate applied](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=cbe496174f58e0ee1683b2aeda57c4e6)